# Setting up dansguardian mac 10.5

Tags: mac-osx, mac, mac-osx-server

I am setting up dansguardian on Mac 10.5 am using a manual from the danguardian website and I have gotten to a point where I am supposed to open file

/etc/rc.d/init.d

However if I go to this location, I cannot find this file.

Any ideas on where I can access this file or do I need to get it from somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Look here: [Setting up daemons on Mac OS X](https://serverfault.com/questions/10564/setting-up-daemons-on-mac-os-x)

You need to do that part a completely different way, since OS X Server does not use init scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) manpage; Sorry if this seems like a RTFM answer.